# How to Create Supplier register through frontend side in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

How can I create Supplier register through front end side in prestashop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a step-by-step here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/prestashop-15/manufacturer-supplier-setup/adding-suppliers.

Comment: I have get Same as admin  Functionality in front side 
this is use for seller account

Comment: I imagine that your 'seller' is like and employee, right? If yes, I recommend you reading about roles: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Managing+Employees

Comment: Yes, I have add Seller and Buyer but this is use only buyer